# Deserialize String Array using Newtonsoft's JSON

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I am attempting to deserialize the prices data from the foursquare Menu's API. However, no matter what I try I get a null value in place of the price.

The data I am trying to parse looks like this:

```
"prices": [
    "(single) $5.00",
    "(double) $9.00"
]
```

I have tried code such as:

```
[JsonProperty("prices")]
public List<string> Prices { get; set; }
```

as well as a variety of other's including replacing List[string] with string and List[string] with a List[ProductPrice] that contained a string. None of these attempts worked.

Does anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Note: The rest of my code works and the menu is deserialized correctly except for the prices so it is not a problem with my web request etc.

Comment: No problem with your (partial)json and property declaration. It seems that the problem lies in the parts you haven't shown us.

Comment: Ah, the problem was indeed my own. It turns out the the prices data is not always returned. Upon further testing it does indeed parse the prices. Thanks, L.B.